# Seria 15 o limite máximo de imagens por Drawable Resource File no Android Studio?

Tags: android, drawable

Gostaria de fazer uma **Animation Drawable** com 18 imagens no Android Studio, porém ao tentar executá-la o aplicativo parava do nada e dava isso no **Android Monitor**:

```
03-16 16:58:26.531 12973-12973/genesysgeneration.animation E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
                                                                                 at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                                                                                 at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:483)
                                                                                 at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:351)
                                                                                 at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:773)
                                                                                 at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1940)
                                                                                 at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:664)
                                                                                 at android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable.inflate(AnimationDrawable.java:280)
                                                                                 at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:867)
                                                                                 at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:804)
                                                                                 at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1925)
                                                                                 at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:664)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable(ResourcesWrapper.java:128)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.TintResources.getDrawable(TintResources.java:45)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:11695)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setBackgroundResource(AppCompatImageView.java:86)
                                                                                 at genesysgeneration.animation.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4466)
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Fiquei encucado com isso, pois não sabia onde estava o erro e não estava acusando nada, então resolvi executar somente uma imagem da minha animação... RESULTOU!!!

Tentei 2, 3, 4... até a 15 deu tudo certo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/an01" android:duration="100"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/an02" android:duration="100"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/an03" android:duration="100"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/an04" android:duration="100"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/an05" android:duration="100"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/an06" android:duration="100"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/an07" android:duration="100"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/an08" android:duration="100"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/an09" android:duration="100"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/an10" android:duration="100"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/an11" android:duration="100"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/an12" android:duration="100"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/an13" android:duration="100"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/an14" android:duration="100"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/an15" android:duration="100"></item>


</animation-list>
```

Quando coloquei 16 imagens, deu erro novamente...

Pensei que poderia ser erro nas imagens propriamente falando, então pulei a 16 e fui para a 17... Erro de novo!!! Mesma coisa com a 18.

Resultado, desconfiei que não fosse erro nas imagens, mas que fosse algum tipo de limite do número total de frames. Modifiquei a **animation-list** para o seguinte:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/an01" android:duration="100"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/an02" android:duration="100"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/an03" android:duration="100"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/an04" android:duration="100"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/an05" android:duration="100"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/an06" android:duration="100"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/an07" android:duration="100"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/an08" android:duration="100"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/an09" android:duration="100"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/an10" android:duration="100"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/an11" android:duration="100"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/an12" android:duration="100"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/an16" android:duration="100"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/an17" android:duration="100"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/an18" android:duration="100"></item>


</animation-list>
```

A imagens 16, 17 e 18 funcionaram, logo desconfiei que era mesmo um limite de 15 frames.

**Gostaria de saber se é um limite mesmo e se há como aumentá-lo ou até mesmo fazer um armengue para exibir uma animação logo após a outra. Desde já agradecido!!!**

**Código da activity:**

```
package genesysgeneration.animation;

import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AnimationDrawable animation;
    private ImageView ivInvisible;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ivInvisible=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivInvisible);
        ivInvisible.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.an00);
        animation=(AnimationDrawable)ivInvisible.getBackground();

    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){

        if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            animation.start();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);

    }

}
```

Comment: Qual a resolução dessas imagens? O mais provável ai é que são imagens muito grandes e por isso está dando o OutOfMemory, pois você não tem memória suficiente para carregar elas, lembrando que o Android limita o máximo que o aplicativo pode usar de RAM

Comment: a média de tamanho das imagem é de 350KB com as dimensões de 720x1280

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu problema é certamente o uso de memória destas imagens e não a quantidade delas em si, tendo em vista que um AnimationDrawable carrega todas as imagens em memória de uma vez só.

Primeiro de tudo é importante entender que o tamanho do arquivo não tem relevância na hora de se usar imagens, ele é apenas o formato da imagem codificada, quando carregada em memória a imagem para poder ser usada é decodificada e, no geral, você vai ter um uso de 4 bytes (32 bits) por cada pixel da imagem, que geralmente é armazenada em memória como ARGB.

Com isso a sua imagem que tem apenas 350kb e resolução de 720x1280, depois de decodificada ocupa cerca de 3,5mb de RAM, com 18 delas você deve precisa de quase 64mb de RAM apenas para essa animação, e ainda não estou nem contando com o caso de usar a imagem em um aparelho com uma densidade de pixels maior, pois no momento que a imagem é carregada o Android vai redimensionar ela de acordo com a tela, então imagine usar ele em um celular com tela 4K, seria fácil cada imagem sua ocupar mais de 10mb de RAM.

E a quantidade máxima de RAM que um aplicativo pode usar varia bastante de um aparelho para outro, e não tem o que fazer quanto a isso, não tem como alterar esse valor.

Você pode testar apenas para confirmar isso usando imagens com uma resolução menor e assim provavelmente vai conseguir usar mais delas na sua animação, mas eu diria que o AnimationDrawable não foi projetado para ser usado desta forma, com animações do tamanho da tela e você provavelmente vai ter que considerar alguma alternativa, como uma animação menor só com a parte da imagem que realmente é animada caso ela tenha uma grande parte estática, ou fazer você mesmo por código a animação desenhando diretamente ela na tela, só que de preferência não deveria usar frames inteiros e sim fazer a animação em si por código.

Comment: De fato. Reduzi pela metade tanto largura quanto altura e resultou. Thanks!!!